# Automapping a Dictionary(Converting Error)

Tags: c#, linq, automapper

I am trying to auto map a two dictionary objects. 
Class to map from

```
public partial class Purchase
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PurchaseId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal? Payment { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool IsPaid { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }

    public virtual Products Products { get; set; }
    public virtual Customers Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Class to Map to

```
   public partial class PurchaseModel
   {
    public int PurchaseId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal? Payment { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool IsPaid { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }

    public virtual Products Products { get; set; }
    public virtual Customers Customer { get; set; }
}
```

My Mapping function:

```
 Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<KeyValuePair<string, Purchase>, KeyValuePair<string, PurchaseModel>>()
                      .ConstructUsing(x => new KeyValuePair<string, PurchaseModel>(x.Key, x.Value)));
```

The Linq statement:

```
  x.Value
```

gives the error Cannot convert from `Purchase` to `PurchaseModel` but it's evident they are the same...

The Linq method that provides the dictionary is:

```
 public async Task<IDictionary<string, List<Purchase>>> GetDaysPurchases(DateTime dateTime)
 {
   var dayspurchases = await cstentity.Purchase.Where(p => p.Date == dateTime).GroupBy(i => i.Customer.Name).ToDictionaryAsync(pur => pur.Key, pur => pur.Select(i => i).ToList());

    return new SortedDictionary<string, List<Purchase>>(dayspurchases);
 }
```

Comment: The dictionary mapping is built in, you don't need to create it.

Comment: It throws an error. Cannot implicitly convert type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add directly map from `Purchase` to a `PurchaseModel` with:

```
            cfg.CreateMap<Purchase, PurchaseModel>();
```

Comment: Mapper.Map<IDictionary<string, List<Purchase>>,IDictionary<string, List<PurchaseModel>>>(dayspurchases); did the trick Thanks